# MongoDb TTL index on updated documents

Tags: mongodb, ttl

I have a mongo collection to clean. I created a ttl index to delete documents older than 1 year. The index works but only on documents inserted after the creation of the index, the old ones are not deleted. For older documents I have created a script that creates a "date" field according to the index specification.

Thx u

**Update**

old and new documents are equals

```js
db.getCollection('collectionOne').createIndex({ "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 10 });
```

**Old Document**
`{ "name" : "MyName", "createdAt": ISODate("2021-01-01T08:24:58.000Z") }`

**New Document**
 `{ "name" : "MyNameOne", "createdAt": ISODate("2021-08-05T16:24:58.000Z") }`

Comment: Provide a sample old and new document and the ttl index details.

Comment: @PoornaSubhash new and old documents are equals